# placeholder not shown in ngselect

Tags: angular

I'm working with ng-select in my angular form ( https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select) the code that I'm using :

```
<ng-select
            formControlName="model"
            name="model"
            id="add_sheet_model"
            [items]="modelItems"
            [multiple]="false"
            [searchable]="false"
            bindLabel="value"
            bindValue="id"
            placeholder="select model"
          >
          </ng-select>
```

the problem is that the placeholder is not displayed when I put [multiple] = "false" but when I put [multiple] = "true" the placeholder is displayed and I don't want my ngselect to be multiple.

Ps: I'm working with angular 10 and ngselect 5.0.3.

Any idea ?

Comment: can you try multiple="false" instead [multiple]="false"

Comment: Well that work but i have a problem i can't use (change)="onFormChange()" event in ngselect

Comment: can you also try (ngModelChange)="onFormChange()"

Comment: U can refer posts: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60377303/how-to-always-display-a-placeholder-of-ng-select I think u can n

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I found the solution finally, it's not in relation to the [multiple] attribute but the way to initialize my FormGroup, this is how I initiated it:

```
model: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
```

well it should be like this :

```
model: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
```

this issue helped me to solve this problem https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select/issues/653

Comment: This works only for reactive forms. For template forms, we have to initialize in ts file the [(ngModel)] property

Answer (score 11):

I had a similar problem, and when I started the page, the ng-select input
showed an x ​​in the right corner. Like that:

[image]

This occurred to me because the variable with formControlName or [(ngModel)] was
initializing with a value. Like that:

*With `ngModel`:

```
nameExample = '';
```

*With `formControlName`:

```
editForm = this.fb.group({
   nameExample: [''],
});
```

The correct way was like that:

*With `ngModel`:

```
nameExample?: string;
```

*With reactive Form:

```
editForm = this.fb.group({
   nameExample: [null],
});
```

An example in html would look something like this:

*With `ngModel`:

```
<ng-select class="custom" id="field_exemplo" name="nameExample" 
    appearance="outline" [trackByFn]="trackById" [items]="listNameExamples!" 
    [(ngModel)]="nameExample" bindValue="id" bindLabel="name" 
    [placeholder]="'APP_TITLE | translate">
</ng-select>
```

*With reactive Form:

```
<ng-select class="custom" id="field_exemplo" name="nameExample" 
    appearance="outline" [trackByFn]="trackById" [items]="listNameExamples!" 
    formControlName="nameExample" bindValue="id" bindLabel="name" 
    [placeholder]="'APP_TITLE | translate">
</ng-select>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `[(ngModel)]="selectedAnything"` in the HTML then on the ts file initialise with

```
this.selectedAnything: any = [];
```